# How do I fix black screen in kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 16.04

So I am trying to use the computer and all I get is a black screen. I don't know how to fix the black screen. Can you help me? I updated Kubutnu 15.10 to 16.04 and all I got was a Black screen. Please. I really need some help.

Comment: I have the same problem with Kubuntu, I tried Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked better. I still to find a reason for the problem but has it surely something to do with my Nvidia Gtx 970. I can't find any errors  in neither sddm.log, dmesg, Xorg.log or syslog. The nouveau or Xorg edgers driver doesn't work. I have 3 installation with other Nvidia graphics cards and they all work fine...